# Entity Validator using DataAnnotations

Tags: .net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I cannot get Validator to use DataAnnotations in my model to validate an object.

Here is my model property that I am trying to validate:

```
[MaxLength(350)]
public string SubSessionName { get; set; }
```

Here is the code I am using to validate it:

```
//validate the subsession
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(subSession, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var validationErrorsList = new List<ValidationResult>();
var subsessionIsValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(subSession, validationContext, validationErrorsList);
```

Even though the SubSessionName property has a length of 401 the Validator still returns true--it should return false. Any ideas on what I might not be wiring up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong TryValidationObject overload. Try this one.

```
var subsessionIsValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
           subSession, validationContext, validationErrorsList, true);
```